# PDFBox does not write the message I want into the page

Tags: java, javafx, pdfbox

I'm looking for at least an hour at my code but I can't find the bug. I'm using PDFBox to create PDF's ([PDFBox HelloWorld Example](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/HelloWorldType1.java?view=markup)). To learn how PDFBox works I just wanted to create some pages with "hello world" and the page number like "hello world 1", "hello world 2" and so on. As you can see I created a for loop to create six pages.

```
private void drawPDF(PDDocument doc, File file) throws IOException {
    for (int pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < 6; pageIndex++) {
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
        doc.addPage(page);
        PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
        String message = "hello world " + (pageIndex + 1);
        float stringHeight = font.getFontDescriptor().getFontBoundingBox().getHeight() * FONT_SIZE;
        PDRectangle pageSize = page.getMediaBox();
        try (PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page)) {
            contents.beginText();
            contents.setFont(font, FONT_SIZE);
            contents.setTextMatrix(Matrix.getTranslateInstance(0, pageSize.getHeight() - stringHeight / 1000f));
            contents.showText(message);
            System.out.println(message + " - " + doc.getNumberOfPages());
            contents.endText();
        }
    }
    doc.save(file);
}
```

In my console I get the following output (first number is pageIndex, second number is doc.getNumberOfPages()):

```
hello world 1 - 1
hello world 2 - 2
hello world 3 - 3
hello world 4 - 4
hello world 5 - 5
hello world 6 - 6
```

This is my load function to view the pdf.

```
private final ObservableList<Image> pdfFilePages = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


private void loadFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    if (file != null) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = null;
        try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r"); FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel()) {
            buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) channel.size());
            channel.read(buffer);
            buffer.flip();

            PDFFile pdfFile = new PDFFile(buffer);
            List<Image> pages = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < pdfFile.getNumPages(); i++) {
                PDFPage page = pdfFile.getPage(i, true);
                System.out.println("page: " + i + " - " + pdfFile.getNumPages());
                java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D bbox = page.getBBox();
                java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, (int) bbox.getWidth(), (int) bbox.getHeight());
                BufferedImage buffImage = new BufferedImage((int) (bbox.getWidth() * 2d),
                        (int) (bbox.getHeight() * 2d), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                java.awt.Image awtImage = page.getImage((int) (bbox.getWidth() * 2.0),
                        (int) (bbox.getHeight() * 2.0), rect, null, true, true);
                java.awt.Graphics2D bufImageGraphics = buffImage.createGraphics();
                bufImageGraphics.drawImage(awtImage, 0, 0, null);

                Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(buffImage, null);
                pages.add(image);
            }
            pdfFilePages.addAll(pages);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I get in my console:

```
page: 0 - 6
page: 1 - 6
page: 2 - 6
page: 3 - 6
page: 4 - 6
page: 5 - 6
```

When I load the pdf file to display the content in my application i get "hello world 1 - 1" for the first and second page. The following pages have "hello world 2 - 2" to "hello world 5 - 5". I don't understand why I get two pages of "hello world 1 - 1". I hope someone can explain to me where I made a mistake.

Comment: Which library do you use for displaying the PDF? `PDFFile` does not appear to be a PDFBox class. My guess: `PDFFile.getPage` wants a 1-based page number and in case of a 0 defaults to page 1.

Comment: in my loadfile method I turn the pdf file to images and store them in my observablelist (pdfFilesPages is of the type observablelist<image>) of images. To display a page, I pick the desired page and create an image view object which I can add to a pane.

Comment: That's not what I asked. I asked *"Which library do you use for displaying the PDF?"*

Comment: sorry. com.sun.pdfview is the library I use to display the pdf

Comment: you were right. The solution is to start the for loop at 1 and to go through it until the index is equal to pdfFile.getNumPages(). getPage() jumps to the first page when the integer is 0. Therefore I get the first page twice. thank you very much :)

Comment: com.sun.pdfview is PDFRenderer, an abandoned project. PDFBox can also convert to images (coincidentally, with a method named `PDFRenderer`).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of mkl I found the bug in my code. The for loop has to start at 1 and run until the index is equal to pdfFile.getNumPages(). The method getPage() return the first page when the index is 0. Because the index is 1 in the second iteration, the first page will be passed twice. The last page won't be passed since the loop has been finished. This seems to be the right approach.

```
private void loadFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    if (file != null) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = null;
        try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r"); FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel()) {
            buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) channel.size());
            channel.read(buffer);
            buffer.flip();

            PDFFile pdfFile = new PDFFile(buffer);
            List<Image> pages = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= pdfFile.getNumPages(); i++) {
                PDFPage page = pdfFile.getPage(i, true);
                System.out.println("page: " + i + " - " + pdfFile.getNumPages());
                java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D bbox = page.getBBox();
                java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, (int) bbox.getWidth(), (int) bbox.getHeight());
                BufferedImage buffImage = new BufferedImage((int) (bbox.getWidth() * 2d),
                        (int) (bbox.getHeight() * 2d), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                java.awt.Image awtImage = page.getImage((int) (bbox.getWidth() * 2.0),
                        (int) (bbox.getHeight() * 2.0), rect, null, true, true);
                java.awt.Graphics2D bufImageGraphics = buffImage.createGraphics();
                bufImageGraphics.drawImage(awtImage, 0, 0, null);

                Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(buffImage, null);
                pages.add(image);
            }
            pdfFilePages.addAll(pages);
        }
    }
}
```